# Is there a faster way to add icons next to urls/links in a web page - alternative to using "onload" event?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, onload

I am writing a Firefox add-on that adds little icons next to all the urls in a web page.

The way I am doing it right now is :

1. window.addEventListener("load", AddIconsToURLs, false);
2. In AddIconsToURLs function:
   Get all elements by tag name "a" 
   For each "a" element, append an "img" element.

However, for some web pages, the icons take a lot of time to appear since the "onload" event takes time.

Is there any faster way to make this happen ? 
Rather than waiting for all the links to load and then adding icons next to each of them, is there any way to add an icon next to a link as soon as that particular link is loaded ?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is another event you can listen to:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", AddIconsToURLs, false);
```

Comment: I know this event works in IE. Does this work for Firefox too ? Is it faster than onload event ?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: I tried it for some pages. Somehow it is working for almost all pages except for google search.

Comment: @userlite that's probably because when you do a search, the results don't come up on a new page, they get loaded onto the page you're already on.

Answer (score 1):

What do you want to do with the images? Anything special? If it is just for the look, much easier would be to load a CSS style sheet in your addon and use the [*`:after`*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/%3aafter) pseudo element:

```
a:after {
  content: url('chrome://youraddon/skin/imagefile.png');
}
```

No JavaScript processing involved :)

You can load a custom CSS file with:

```
var sss = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/content/style-sheet-service;1"]
          .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIStyleSheetService);
var ios = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/io-service;1"]
          .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIIOService);
var uri = ios.newURI("chrome://youraddon/skin/cssfile.css", null, null);

if(!sss.sheetRegistered(uri, sss.AGENT_SHEET)) {
    sss.loadAndRegisterSheet(uri, sss.AGENT_SHEET);
}
```

See also [*Using the Stylesheet Service*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_the_Stylesheet_Service).

Comment: Thanks for the reply . 
I have a mouseover function for each icon which takes the corresponding URL and does some further processing.

Comment: Current sequence is : link mouseover -> icon appears -> icon mouseover -> take link and do further processing.
Is there any way to achieve this using a combination of CSS and something else ?

Comment: @userlite: No seems you can't access CSS generated content, as it is not added to DOM. Too bad, seemed to be a nice way :)